# Jquery td cell width always 0

Tags: jquery, html-table, cell

i have this table created.
This table should have same column width for the whole table.
If the cells have different values, so the table normaly grows.
But i want the table to have identical columns within a given table width.

Example:
The screen is created in 2 segments, left and right. The right segment has the table, but the width of this segment is greater than the table width. So i can calculate every column with the same width value to show this table with same column width.

Looks like this

```
  Posart   |   Datum    |
1234567890 | 1234567890 |
   1234    | 12.12.2019 |

<table  id="Auftragspositionen" class="standardliste" summary="">
<tr><th id="Posart">Posart</th><th id="Datum">Datum</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td headers="Posart"><div class="left noborder">001.00<br/>Z <br/>Zeit</div></td>
<td headers="Datum"><div class="middle noborder">12.03.2018</div></td>
</tr></table>

And my jQuery select is this !

b2=$('#Auftragspositionen');
b2.find("tr th").children("td").each(function(i) {
        tdWidth = $(this).width();
        alert(i + 'td width is ' + $(this).tdWidth);
        });
```

My question is, that every cell td width=0 ???
Why it is ?

Answer (score 1):

Observe this part of your code:

```
tdWidth = $(this).width();                     // here you define the tdWidth variable
alert(i + 'td width is ' + $(this).tdWidth);
```

In the second line, instead of accessing the `tdWidth` variable you just created, when you use `$(this).tdWidth` you actually try to access a jQuery property called `tdWidth` which doesn't exist.

So the solution is to really access your variable (lose the `$(this).` there). Also it is better to declare the variable locally, using `var`.

```
var tdWidth = $(this).width();         // using var here
alert(i + ' td width is ' + tdWidth);  // not $(this).tdWidth !
```

For the demo below I changed the selector as well (from `b2.find("tr th")` to `b2.find("tr")`, because the former finds `th`s that are children of `tr` and `th`s have no `td`s children - which is what you search later with `.children("td")`):

```js
b2 = $('#Auftragspositionen');
b2.find("tr").children("td").each(function(i) {
  var tdWidth = $(this).width();
  alert(i + ' td width is ' + tdWidth);
});
```

```css
table, tr, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Auftragspositionen" class="standardliste" summary="">
  <tr>
    <th id="Posart">Posart</th>
    <th id="Datum">Datum</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td headers="Posart">
      <div class="left noborder">001.00<br/>Z <br/>Zeit</div>
    </td>
    <td headers="Datum">
      <div class="middle noborder">12.03.2018</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi acdcjunior, thank you for your response, i have seen my mistake. Now it is working. But this script will find every "td", but to calculate the table it is only necessary to find the first line, or the first row (tr). It is possible to change the script for only the the first row ?

Comment: Try `b2.find("tr").children("th")` is that it?

Comment: Hi acdcjunior, but this is only the heading. The width of the heading is different from the data row, i think.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the correct is `b2.find("tr:eq(0)").children("td")`. It will pick up the first row only.